# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file - Cause unknown

Tags: android, android-layout

I get the following exception when I launch my activity:

```
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nykkos.personalize/com.nykkos.personalize.screens.SummaryCostScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:823)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:729)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at com.nykkos.personalize.screens.SummaryCostScreen.onCreate(SummaryCostScreen.java:37)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  ... 11 more
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  ... 26 more
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020000 a=-1 r=0x7f020000}
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1899)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:109)
05-28 13:34:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  ... 29 more
05-28 13:34:09.549: W/ActivityManager(77):   Force finishing activity com.nykkos.personalize/.screens.SummaryCostScreen
```

THe error in activity is from:

```
setContentView(R.layout.summarycost_layout);
```

The xml file summarycost_layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
    android:id="@+id/includeTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/titlebar_layout" />

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/summaryCostListview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white" >
    </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutTotal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTotal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Total Cost(0/0)"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$0"
        android:textColor="@color/blue" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:text="@string/select_all"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAccept"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:text="@string/accept"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the titlebar_layout referred in the above xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgBack"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:onClick="onBackClick"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow_back" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgForward"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:onClick="onForwardClick"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow_for" />
```

It seems , the issue is from `<ImageView` of the titlebar_layout.

I'm a little bit lost with where to look for the cause of the exception. I even don't know if this is really an issue in this layout file etc.

How would you go about finding the cause for this issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Clean your project (e.g., Project > Clean in Eclipse), then try it again and see if it helps.

Comment: tried many a times, no luck

Comment: Look at your `R.java` file and see what `0x7f020000` maps to.

Comment: it maps to `arrow_back`

Comment: Is that the only occurrence of `0x7f020000` in `R.java`? Do you have only one `R.java`, or do you have others (e.g., for Android library projects that you are importing)?

Comment: yes, I checked. That is the only occurrence. And I do not import any Android Library project to my current project. Infact I am using this in many other xml's as title layout

Comment: Sorry, then, I'm stumped.

Comment: Is arrow_back a bitmap or an XML drawable?

Comment: @shoe rat - it is a png image. I have observed one thing now, I have commented the  arrow_back references in code, now it gives me exception from button_bg references which is another png image. I do not understand what the real problem is

Comment: I see. It could be that system is failing to find the matching resource. See ["Providing the Best Device Compatibility with Resources"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#Compatibility) and check if that is not the case. Specifically, _If you use a new resource qualifier, but maintain code compatibility with older versions of Android, then when an older version of Android runs your application, it will crash if you do not provide default resources, because it cannot use the resources named with the new qualifier._

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the exact issue advised by the OP in the past and @shoe rat has alluded to the correct answer above in his comments.

I'm guessing your PNG drawables are not located in the base 'drawable' folder where Android can find a match on the device or emulator you are testing with.  You have probably inadvertently copied your arrow_back and button_bg drawables into for example, drawable-large and drawable-xlarge but are testing on a device or emulator that is say small (320x280). In my example the matching rules can't find a match for the small screen size hence the android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path) error results.

So for a quick test, copy your arrow_back and button_bg drawables (plus any others you have) to the drawable folder and it should compile and run without error because the drawables in the drawable folder will always be found and used as a fallback.  Then of course ensure you create appropriate sized drawables for each screen size to suit all screen variations and read the '[How Android Finds the Best-matching Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch)' to better understand the drawable matching process in Android.